# Git search repo for the names of all files that have ever contained a string

Tags: git

I need to find every instance of a particular string being added or removed from any file in a repository.

So far I've tried

```
git log -S'string' --all
git log --follow -p path/to/file
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only <hash>
git diff $(git log -S'string' -i --all --pretty="%H") | tee output.txt
```

in various combinations.

All I can get is a list of thousands of files that were part of commits that involved 'string'. I need a list of only those files that have, at some point, contained 'string'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git log -Sstring -p` provides all the output, and it's easy enough to extract the file names:

```
git log -p -Sstring --all | grep '^---\|^+++' | grep -v /dev/null \
                          | sed 's%^\(---\|+++\) [ab]/%%'
```

Comment: +1 I didn't know `-p` would only output patches for matching files when combined with `-S`, very useful!

Comment: @GabrielePetronella `git log` does the hard work - grep/sed only look convoluted, but are in fact trivial. It would be nice to have a diff option to only list the file names, but I have yet to find one that would work in conjunction with `git log` as the OP needed it here.

Comment: That wasn't a critique to your answer, I'm simply amazed every time I realize how bash expressions can become so awful so quickly. Sleek solution, though ;)

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Thanks, I didn't really take it as a critique, I only "defended" it in the spirit of teaching, i.e. spreading the joy of shell programming. :)

Comment: This worked perfectly: `git log -p -Sstring --all | grep '^---\|^+++' | grep -v /dev/null`
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Use git grep

```
git log --all --format=format:%H | xargs -n 1 git grep  -i -I --full-name "perl"
```

This one will search for occurrences of perl for each commit, output is like this.

```
c3eab7df88fdc5e848fd13fdab4298afd24f9ee8:bugzilla/bugzilla.pl:#!/usr/bin/perl
```

Might actually not solve your problem as you want to know when it is added and removed

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shell script to iterate over all of the files currently tracked by Git, and then determine whether or not each file has ever contained the string:

```
for f in $(git ls-files); do
  commits=$(git log -S'string' --oneline -- $f | wc -l)
  if [[ $commits -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo $f
  fi
done
```

This won't list any files that used to contain the string, but have subsequently been deleted.